# How to find if web element is invisible or executed through Javascript

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to input some text into text field using the following robotframework code and web element is not getting selected.Can someone suggest/guide me how this can achieved or how to identify if web element is invisible or executed through Javascript .Following is the example that I have tried.

```
*** Settings ***
Library          Selenium2Library
Suite Teardown   close all browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Example using custom selenium keyword
    Open browser   https://10.12.60.110:21412/logon.jsp  browser=chrome
    Input Text       //input[@id='_id0:logon:USERNAME']      Administrator
    Input Text       //input[@id='_id0:logon:PASSWORD']      Welcome1
```

I have tried using execute JAVAscript command in robot framework Selenium2Library.

```
Export CSV from SAP BO
    Open browser   https://10.12.60.200:8443/BOE/BI    browser=chrome
    Execute Javascript      document.getElementById('_id0:logon:USERNAME').value='Administrator' ; 
    Execute Javascript      document.getElementById('_id0:logon:PASSWORD').value='Admin1' ; 
    Click Button       LOGIN
```

I have tried using xpath and element is not getting selected using xpath.

```
<input id="_id0:logon:USERNAME" name="_id0:logon:USERNAME" type="text">
```

xpath is `//input[@id='_id0:logon:USERNAME']`  but output is no matching nodes.PFA screenshot  below  [image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried indirectly: `//div[contains(@class, 'logonInput')]/input`?

Comment: @A.Kootstra Thanks for replying . I have tried but it says no matching nodes. I am not sure whether the element is getting hidden or how to get the element.

Comment: Have you tried some escaping? semi-column : is normally used for "namespaces". Not sure how much of that will kick in (It's HTML, not XML) but still.

Comment: At what point in the DOM are you unable to find the elements? Is it even the root node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks like coming from the fact the login is in an iframe - look at your first screenshot, the document starts with html > body > **frame**. So switching to it should make the rest of yoyr sample code work:

```
Select Frame     a_locator_for_that_iframe
```